# No me funciona nth-child() y no sé por qué

Tags: css3, selectores

He probado de muchas formas seleccionar el último `article` y nada.... intenté con `last-child`, le agregué la `class="articulo"` (que no era necesaria) y sigue sin funcionar.

Lo resolví con la línea que esta comentada, pero quiero saber cuál es el error que estoy teniendo, porque no es la idea tener que poner un id.

Éste es mi código:

```css
#sliders #sobreMi #ejemplos article:nth-child(4) {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

/*
#sliders #sobreMi #ejemplos article#ultimo{
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="sliders">
  <section id="sobreMi">
    <div id="ejemplos">
      <article class="articulo">
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong...></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" >
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong...></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" >
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong...></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" id="ultimo">
        <div class="diseños" >
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong...></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el código tiene un error: no se está cerrando bien la etiqueta `<strong>` porque la etiqueta de cierre es `</strong...>` (con esos tres puntos). Eso va a hacer que la estructura de tu página no sea la que te esperas.

Si quitas esos `...`, entonces las etiquetas y la estructura de la página ya serán correctas y el CSS se aplica correctamente:

```css
#sliders #sobreMi #ejemplos article:nth-child(4) {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

/*
#sliders #sobreMi #ejemplos article#ultimo{
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="sliders">
  <section id="sobreMi">
    <div id="ejemplos">
      <article class="articulo">
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" >
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" >
        <div class="diseños">
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="articulo" id="ultimo">
        <div class="diseños" >
          <figure><img src="" alt=""></figure>
          <div class="subeInfo">
            <h4>Diseño de <strong>logotipos</strong></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing elit.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: no te puedo creer que se me quedaran esos tres puntos del texto anterior.....jajaja. muchisimas gracias!